# ApplicationBarIconButton Not Working in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

`ApplicationBarIconButton` is not working in my WP7 project using C# . When I click the appbar icon button nothing is happening. I have written the event handler for click event and also set `IsEnabled = true`.

When I open any new project and try to use the `ApplicationBarIconButton` it works. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a bit more detail than this :-) can you show the markup for the app bar and the code it is calling perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using 7.0 with a `Launcher` or `Chooser`? You might be running into [the issue mentioned here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/e079d99e-d2ac-47ab-a87e-f4ce0d3660d5).